# Безопасность публичных точек доступа

Tags: безопасность, https, wifi

Довольно часто можно встретить рекомендацию не пользоваться онлайн-банкингом через открытый wifi. Например, [свежая публикация](https://rg.ru/2021/04/10/ekspert-rasskazala-kak-zashchitit-svoj-schet-v-onlajn-banke.html):

> Заходите в личный кабинет на сайте банка или в приложение банка на смартфоне только через защищенный Wi-Fi или мобильный интернет вашего сотового оператора (открытые публичные Wi-Fi-сети не гарантируют конфиденциальности).

Но ведь все банки уже давным давно работают по https, который защищает от перехвата конфиденциальной информации. Так в чём же смысл данного совета или он уже давно потерял актуальность?

Ещё я встречал источники, которые против использования открытого вайфая, но вполне довольны использованием публичного защищённого. Действительно ли в этих случаях есть разница в доступных другим людям (пользователям или владельцу) данным?

Comment: Просто предположение - уберечь пользователя потенциального [даунгрейда HTTPS через sslstip](https://eax.me/sslstrip/). Хотя если сервер настроен правильно, этого не должно произойти

Comment: @Андрей Банковские приложения написаны достаточно разумно, чтобы проверить наличие SSL и правильный пининг сертификата.

Comment: Возможно, речь о каком-нибудь DNS-спуфинге сайта банка на поддельной точке... Хотя в современных реалиях и этот сценарий маловероятен

Comment: Подмена DNS ничего не даст - не получится подписать данные от банка без сертификата банка

Comment: @gbg, но подождите, разве нельзя подделать SSL-сертификат?

Comment: @Андрей, нельзя. Потому что телефон проверяет цепочку сертификатов вплоть до корневого (а приложение банка может и будет вовсе использовать УЦ самого банка). Компроментация такого уровня не под силу даже государствам, не то что кулхацкерам.

Comment: @gbg, знаете, в эпоху, когда беспардонно звонят с номера «900», я уже ничему не удивлюсь)

Comment: @Андрей, а тут все просто - вежливо кладете трубку, а потом сами обращаетесь в поддержку банка **через приложение**

Comment: @gbg, да это само собой... Но вот сама по себе техническая возможность подобной аферы удручает

Comment: @gbg теоретически можно добыть действительный сертификат у не совсем аккуратного/честного центра сертификации — кажется, подобное уже уже было на практике пару раз...

Comment: Приложение банка может (и будет, вероятнее всего) использовать и пинить серт, выданный самим банком. А стырить серт гугла малореально

Comment: @gbg во-первых, не все пользуются приложением, а во-вторых, зная, в какой стране я живу, я очень сильно сомневаюсь, что кто-то реально додумался запинить серт)

Comment: Инфобез - это всегда воронка. Пининг сертификата защищает от атаки, когда Еве доступно устройство (что не наш случай), либо когда у УЦ увели корневой серт (что имеет крайне низкую вероятность), так что эти атаки относятся к уже узкой стороне воронки

Comment: @andreymal, были такие единичные случаи. Но ведь весьма маловероятно, что такое провернёт владелец какой-то кафешки с вайфаем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Грамотно устроенные банковские приложения (именно приложения, а не сайт в браузере)

   - проверяют наличие SSL, имеют внутренний механизм валидации сертификата ([Cert Pining](https://www.emaro-ssl.ru/blog/ssl-pinning-for-android/)). Так что при вмешательстве в трафик они (приложения) просто сломаются - то есть, приложение перестанет работать и выдаст ошибку. Никакие данные при этом переданы никуда не будут.
2. Сайт банка

   - Да, тут можно попасть под SSL Strip и это угроза (если пользователь не умеет надежно убеждаться в том, что подключился по https)
3. Что еще можно украсть:

   - Список посещенных сайтов по HTTPS (БЕЗ адресов страниц), [или даже только IP, без доменных имен](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38727920/5533854) - можно узнать, что зашли в facebook, но нельзя узнать учетку
   - один из случайных MAC адресов вашего устройства, и таким образом, узнать его марку и модель.

Что касается самой статьи, в ней много рекомендаций, которые дают ложное чувство безопасности:

- Скачивать приложения только из сторов - в сторах полно мусора, хорошо если только с попапами
- 2FA через SMS - это слабенькая защита, потому что SMS относительно легко скомпромитировать. 2FA через приложение (а лучше, 2FA через токен) - лучше. Хотя бы, SMS не должно приходить на ту же трубу, на которой стоит приложение банка, иначе это 1FA
- защищенная папка перестает быть защищенной, когда устройство разлочено первый раз после включения
- приложения для определения входящих вызовов весело сливают все входящие и адресную книгу налево

Comment: Не могу написать в комментах, не хватает рейтинга.
Подскажите по пункту "проверяют наличие SSL, имеют внутренний механизм валидации сертификата (Cert Pining). Так что при вмешательстве в трафик они просто сломаются."
Что значит сломаются? Станут уязвимы? но ведь тогда и любой провайдер может сделать тоже самое. Смысл сертификата установленного заранее в приложении как раз в том чтобы даже провайдер не мог помешать корректному обмену? В чем тогда разница между приложением и браузером, можете пояснить плиз.

Comment: Не "механизмы защиты сломаются", а приложение выдаст ошибку и перестанет работать. Никакие данные при этом переданы никуда не будут.

Comment: Вообще для защиты от SSL Strip изобрели HSTS Preload List, но почему-то тот же Сбербанк этим не воспользовался...

Comment: @gbg Подозреваю, что банковские сайты давно в захардкоженных в браузер списках сайтов, которые можно открывать только по https? Отдать список посещённых сайтов вроде ничем не грозит? MAC сеть получит при подключении - тут банки вообще не при чём. И тоже вроде не сильно приватная инфа?